# в компоненте не отображает актуальный стейт стора (Mobx) при двойной деструктуризации

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx

Есть стор mobx, представленный в виде класса, у него есть метод запроса данных через REST API

На UI - нажатие на кнопку вызывает данный метод и устанавливает флаг загрузки (loadingTestRun) на true, при завершении выполнения запроса снова false, при этом во время обработки запроса должен отображаться лоэдер.

Есть хук, возвращающий стор, хук работает по всему приложению и отрабатывает хорошо. Все компоненты, взаимодействующие со стором обёрнуты в useObserve, проблема обнаружена именно в компоненте с двойной деструктуризацией

Проблема в том, что, если обращаться к loadingTestRun через rulesStore.loadingTestRun, то всё отрабатывает хорошо

```
  const { rulesStore } = useStores()
```

Но если деструктурирую ещё, то в в компонете, где ожидается увидеть загрузку - loadingTestRun остаётся false, при выполнении запроса

```
 const { rulesStore : { loadingTestRun } } = useStores()
```

Пример RootStore

```
class RootStore implements IRootStore {
  rulesStore: RulesStore
  groupStore: GroupStore
  projectStore: ProjectStore
  intervalsStore: IntervalsStore
  eventsStore: EventsStore
  templateStore: TemplateStore

  //Сюда подключаем все новые store и передаем в них this
  constructor() {
    this.rulesStore = new RulesStore(this)
    this.groupStore = new GroupStore(this)
    this.projectStore = new ProjectStore(this)
    this.intervalsStore = new IntervalsStore(this)
    this.eventsStore = new EventsStore(this)
    this.templateStore = new TemplateStore(this)
  }
}

class RulesStore implements IRulesStore {
  ...
  loadingTestRun = false
}
```

Comment: как объявлены сторы?

Comment: Сам же ответил на свой вопрос. Так не отрабатывает ...

Comment: Что значит "всё отрабатывает хорошо"? Как вы убеждаетесь, что всё хорошо? Если loadingTestRun = false после присваивания, то значит он таким был на момент вызова useStores. А если вы получили объект по ссылке и когда-то потом обратились к его свойству loadingTestRun, то значение будет актуально на момент обращения к свойству. Пробовали задебажить?

Comment: @Grundy несколько разных сторов, реализованных на классах, объеденнёных в одном RootStore (тоже класс)

Comment: приведи [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: @ЕгорБанин убеждаюсь, что всё хорошо, когда вижу лоэдер на экране, во время выполнения запроса:)
Да, дебажил в методе класса (обращение к серверу), там это поле изменяется на  true, перед началом запроса, после этого становится false

Comment: @Grundy добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: как ты связываешь rulesStore с mobx?

Comment: @Vasilii задебажить надо ответ на вопрос: "когда меняется свойство при обращении к серверу _относительно_ того, когда выполняется присваивание в компоненте?" То есть проверить, не получается ли так, что в компоненте, использующем `const { rulesStore : { loadingTestRun } } = useStores()`, неактуальное значение `loadingTestRun` из за того, что присвоение случилось раньше смены значения при запросе.

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, всё сводится к

```
var state = {
    rulesStore: {
        loadingTestRun: false,
    },
};
function useStores() {
    return state;
}
function changeState() {
    state.rulesStore.loadingTestRun = true;
}

const { rulesStore } = useStores();
const { rulesStore : { loadingTestRun } } = useStores();
changeState(); 
console.log(rulesStore.loadingTestRun, loadingTestRun);
```

Ни mobx, ни реализация стора тут ни при чём. Стэйт меняется асинхронно и это происходит позже, чем присваивание.

Comment: mobX следит за изменение стейта этого стора, ему не важно, асинхронно он меняется или нет (хотя, мб асинхронщину надо обернуть в runInAction).
Собственно хук всегда возвращает актуальное состояние стора

Comment: @Vasilii да, хук возвращает актуальное состояние на момент вызова хука. Если при этом вы получаете ссылку на это состояние, то при его изменении вы увидите это изменение по ссылке. Но если вы получили значение (не ссылку), то при изменении стэйта ваша копия значения не поменяется. Именно этим отличается рабочий вариант `const { rulesStore } = useStores()` (тут у вас ссылка) от нерабочего `const { rulesStore : { loadingTestRun } } = useStores()` (тут у вас не ссылка, а копия значения).